# Extracting Oracle native connection (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) from java.sql.Connection in Ibatis 2.3 with JDK 5

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ibatis, xmltype

I need to create a oracle.xdb.XMLType from org.w3c.dom.Document. To create XMLType a native JDBC connection is required. I'm able to get java.sql.Connection but not able to Extact native connection(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](https://code.google.com/p/ora-jdbc-source/source/browse/trunk/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.java?r=7) code, `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` is a subclass of `java.sql.Connection`.

So you may be able to type-cast from the latter to the former ... assuming that you got the connection object from an Oracle JDBC driver.

If the `Connection` an ibatis proxy, then the `unwindConnection` method on [this page](http://www.apachebookstore.com/confluence/oss/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15597591&decorator=printable) may be helpful.

Comment: I tried that already and I got the erro: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection. This is an ibatis implementation.